# Using python and xlrd, what is the best way to read 2 columns from a spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, xlrd

I have an excel spreadsheet that has 2 columns. Something like this

|ColA |  ColB |
|Key  | Value |
|1    | test  |
|2    | test2 |
|3    | test4 |

and I want to read these two columns into a dictionary.  I currently have this working but can't figure out how to extract out each key value pair

```
  sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
  for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
      print sh.row_values(rownum)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close.  If you want to build a dictionary from the a sheet that only contains keys and values, in the first two columns, you can simply do

```
print dict(sh.row_values(rownum) for rownum in range(sh.nrows))
```

As John Y mentioned, if you need to extract two specific columns with indexes i (keys) and j (values), you can do instead:

```
print dict((sh.cell_value(rownum, i), sh.cell_value(rownum, j)) for rownum in range(sh.nrows))
```

The key point is that `dict()` can build a dictionary from an iterable of (key, value) tuples.

Comment: in my case i only have two columns populated but what if there was 20 columns . .how does dict know what is the key and what is the value ?

Comment: @leora: Then instead of `sh.row_values(rownum)` you would specify the two values you are interested in; for example, the tuple `(sh.cell_value(rownum, k), sh.cell_value(rownum, v))`.

Comment: @EOL: Please do some or all of (1) Read John Y's suggestion again (2) Try executing your code on Leora's data (3) Read the docs: https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html#sheet.Sheet.row_values-method

Comment: @JohnMachin: typo fixed. (Side note: I would have appreciated if you had been less condescending with me about what was a simple, quite innocuous typo. Simply editing the answer and fixing the typo would have been a nicer and more efficient way of contributing.)

Comment: @EOL: I'm sorry, we appear to be ascribing different meanings to "typo" (edit distance of 5 between 2 method names, x 2, is a typo?) and "innocuous" (produces `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`).

Comment: @JohnMachin: the original answer (with "row_value" instead of "cell_value"), along with John Y's quoted remark made the error easy to fix for many people; this is what I meant by "innocuous" error.  So, I would simply like to suggest that you simply edit the answer, next time, if your goal is to help fixing something simple like this.